1940-60s movie about a priest who dates a woman
In the 60s I saw this old movie on tv about a guy who was studying to be a priest or pastor who wore a collar or maybe he was on some kind of break.  He meets a woman and does not tell her that he is connected to the church and kind of dates her as he decides what to do with his life.  He is also close to his sister who is pregnant.  Something bad happens to his sister and she has complications and he rushes to the hospital.  They ask his permission to end the pregnancy to save the mother, but as a priest he cannot approve it and the mother dies but the baby lives. I believe the man does not pursue the relationship with the girl and goes back to the clergy. It's a movie about a religious younger man who is at a crossroads on his future in the church. 
Is this a real movie or did I dream this?       

"Is this a real movie or did I dream this."  If you dreamed it I suggest you jot down your dreams and hire someone to develop them into screen-plays.  I'd watch that movie if the story was well handled!  :)

I think this might be The Cardinal (1963).
The incident with his sister seems to be a relatively small part of the film. The sysnopsis from imdb has this:

Stephen Fermoyle has grown up in Boston at the turn of the twentieth
  century knowing that his destiny lies with the Catholic priesthood.
  Finally finishing his studies in Rome, he returns to America full of
  certitude and ambition to one day join the College of Cardinals. But
  his road to that office is a long one, paved with crises. In Boston,
  he must decide whether to save the life of his sister or her unborn
  child, conceived out of wedlock. In Austria, he confronts the question
  of whether to remain with the priesthood or abandon his oath so that
  he can be with the woman he loves. In Georgia, he contends with Rome's
  indifference in the face of racial bigotry. And in Austria, he finds
  himself personally involved in the church's dealings with the Third
  Reich.

Perhaps the trailer will trigger some memories.
